# equality checks between 2 fields using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the parent categories.

Therefore i need to write,

where `CategoryID` HAS a `ParentCategoryID` of 0

`CategoryID` could be 30 but if it has a `ParentCategoryID` of 0 then you know its the parent category.

This is my SQL so far:

```
SELECT        CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, Name, Published, Deleted, PictureID
FROM          Nop_Category
WHERE         (Deleted = 0) 
AND           (Published = 1) 
AND           (CategoryID = ParentCategoryID = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform equality checks against two fields, use the AND operator and specify the fieldname twice.

```
SELECT        CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, Name, Published, Deleted, PictureID 
FROM          Nop_Category 
WHERE         (Deleted = 0)  
AND           (Published = 1)  
AND           (CategoryID = ParentCategoryID AND ParentCategoryID = 0)
```

But you could also write it like so and achieve the same results:

```
SELECT        CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, Name, Published, Deleted, PictureID 
FROM          Nop_Category 
WHERE         (Deleted = 0)  
AND           (Published = 1)  
AND           (CategoryID = 0 AND ParentCategoryID = 0)
```

However, in your question, you mentioned that CategoryID could be 30, so your query won't work.  You'll likely want to leave out the CategoryID or specify a specific categoryId through a parameter:

```
SELECT        CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, Name, Published, Deleted, PictureID, 
FROM          Nop_Category 
WHERE         (Deleted = 0)  
AND           (Published = 1)  
AND           (CategoryID = @categoryID AND ParentCategoryID = 0)
```

EDIT:

> so if the categoryID is the same as the CetegoryParentID i know its a
>   child.

Generally when I do self-related tables, I use NULL for the ParentId which tells me that the current row is the parent.  If you're using 0 for null, then a record with a CategoryId of 30 and a ParentCategoryId of 30 means it's neather a child nor a parent.

```
ID  PID  Value
0   0    Top Level - must exist for referential integrity
1   0    Child of "Top Level"
2   0    Another child of "Top Level"
3   1    Child of "Child of Top Level"
```

In this scenerio, you can only have 1 top level category, ALL others will be children (even though you consider a ParentCategoryId of 0 a parent, it still must live under CategoryId 0)

Using NULL

```
ID  PID  Value
1   Null Top Level cat 1
2   Null Top Level cat 2
3   1    Child of "Top Level cat 1"
4   2    Child of "Top Level cat 2"
```

In this scenerio, I can easily find ALL top level categories

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Category WHERE pid IS NULL
```

Or, if I want the top category for a specific category

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Category WHERE CategoryId = 1 AND ParentCategoryId is null
```

And my referential integrity is completely in tact.

To locate immediate children of a parent, simply pass in the categoryid of the parent you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Category WHERE ParentCategoryId = 1
```

Comment: While syntactically correct, it doesn't make much sense - both `CategoryID` and `ParentCategoryID` would be 0.

Comment: Correct... you could say CatId = 0 and ParentCatId = 0 and achieve the same results.

Comment: how do i check for a child? eg, CategoryID is the same as ParentCategoryID

Comment: @Super1 - the CategoryID and the ParentCategoryID should never be the same, otherwise it breaks the hierarchy.  A child will ALWAYS have a parentId that is not the same as it's own Id, that's what makes it a child.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me. I am just trying to learn on a Sunday evening! Posted an extension to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384940/display-sub-categories-using-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, Name, Published, Deleted, PictureID
FROM          Nop_Category
WHERE         Deleted = 0
AND           Published = 1
AND           ParentCategoryID = 0
```

Comment: You answered my question thanks. But how do I write, `CategoryID == ParentCategoryID`

Comment: Doesn't take into account CategoryID

Comment: so if the categoryID is the same as the CetegoryParentID i know its a child.