# display sub categories using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nopcommerce

OK this is getting confusing so I decided to write a new question.

I need to check if a row in my category table is a child category. I then need to check which parent category the child is part of?

A parent category has a categoryID and a ParentCategoryID of 0
A child category has a categoryID and a ParentCategoryID eg 30.

**Category Table:**

```
ID PCID NAME
10  0   Computers
11  10  Software
12  10  Hardware
```

**This is what Ive tried:**

This will display the parent categories(because PCID 0 is the parent):

```
SELECT        CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, Name, Published, Deleted, PictureID
FROM          Nop_Category
WHERE        (Deleted = 0) 
AND          (Published = 1) 
AND          (ParentCategoryID = 0)
```

Comment: Your query should return 1 record, "Computers".  So what exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: Looking to return the child categories so that I can use them in my repeater control. So when the user hovers on a parent then child items show up.

Comment: OK, then look at the bottom of my answer - you want ParentCategoryID = 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self join back to the table to find the actual parent of child.

```
SELECT        c1.CategoryID, c2.ParentCategoryID, c1.Name, c2.Name as ParentName, c1.Published, c1.Deleted, c1.PictureID
FROM          Nop_Category c1
JOIN          Nop_Category c2 on c1.ParentCategoryId = c2.CategoryId
WHERE        (c1.Deleted = 0)  
AND          (c1.Published = 1)  
AND          (c1.ParentCategoryID = 10)
```

This would return both children of the category "Computers".  Is that what you're looking for?

Of course, you can turn this around to display all the children of a specific parent or from all parents:

```
SELECT c.*, p.* -- shortened, but you should pick specific columns

FROM Nop_Category p -- parent
JOIN Nop_Category c ON c.ParentCategoryId = p.CategoryId -- children

WHERE p.ParentCategoryId = 0 -- all top level parents


SELECT c.*, p.* -- shortened, but you should pick specific columns

FROM Nop_Category p -- parent
JOIN Nop_Category c ON c.ParentCategoryId = p.CategoryId -- children

WHERE p.CategoryId = 10 -- only the "Computers" category
```

Or, if you just want the children of category "Computers", change your ParentCategoryId to 10

```
SELECT        CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, Name, Published, Deleted, PictureID  
FROM          Nop_Category  
WHERE        (Deleted = 0)   
AND          (Published = 1)   
AND          (ParentCategoryID = 10)
```

Comment: could i do ParentCategoryID > 0

Comment: scratch that, i need to pass a value to determine the ParentCategoryID in order to display the child categories.

Comment: sweet, you've guided me on a weekend. There should be more people like you in this world. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: How about a query that returns the Parent and then child, parent and then child. OR would that not be possible given my current set up?

Comment: actually scratch that too, it looks like the system already groups then up like that when you run a basic select query.